# tooltip is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

The view:

```
<table class="table table-hover">

<?php 
foreach ($query as $row){
    echo  '<tr ><td >
        <label class="checkbox">
        '.form_checkbox('delete[]', $row['link']).anchor("site/see_art/".$row['article_id'],$row['title'],'class="abc"').'
        <div class="tooltip-inner">'.$row['description'].'</div></td><td>'.substr($row['pub_date'], 5, 12).
        '
        </label></td></tr>'
```

JS:

```
<script>
$(".checkbox").mouseenter(function(){
    clearTimeout($('.tooltip-inner').data('timeoutId'));
    $('.tooltip-inner').show(200);
}).mouseleave(function(){
    var timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
        $('.tooltip-inner').hide(200);
    }, 650);
    $('.tooltip-inner').data('timeoutId', timeoutId); 
});

$(".tooltip-inner").mouseenter(function(){
    clearTimeout($('.tooltip-inner').data('timeoutId'));
}).mouseleave(function(){
    var timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
        $('.tooltip-inner').hide(200);
    }, 650);
    $('.tooltip-inner').data('timeoutId', timeoutId); 
});
</script>
```

I have a view where I display some titles. The tooltip works but in this way : when I hover a title it displays me the description for every title like I hover all the titles even that I hover only one title. I want when I hover a title to display only his description. I don't  know how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For jQuery selector on .tooltip-inner use `$('.tooltip-inner', this)` instead. This will select only the tooltip inside the .checkbox label.

**JavaScript**

```
$(".checkbox").mouseenter(function(){
    var $tooltip = $('.tooltip-inner', this);
    clearTimeout($tooltip.data('timeoutId'));
    $tooltip.show(200);
}).mouseleave(function(){
    var $tooltip = $('.tooltip-inner', this),
        timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
        $tooltip.hide(200);
    }, 650);
    $tooltip.data('timeoutId', timeoutId); 
});

$(".tooltip-inner").mouseenter(function(){
    clearTimeout($(this).data('timeoutId'));
}).mouseleave(function(){
    var $tooltip = $(this),
        timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
        $tooltip.hide(200);
    }, 650);
    $tooltip.data('timeoutId', timeoutId); 
});
```

Also, your html markup is incorrect. You're closing table data before closing label tag. Here is a fiddle with working example: http://jsfiddle.net/JWyLU/

Comment: you don't understand. the tooltip it works but when i hover a title is like i hover all the titles. i believe in js is the issue

Comment: Please clarify, which title? you only have hover on the label and the tooltip div defined.

Comment: Maybe i wasn't clear enough. The selector you use, returns an array of all the tooltips on the site. Adding _this_ to the query searches only within the hovered .checkbox label and returns the appropriate tooltip to show. Not all of them.

Comment: thanks matej now it works. Another problem is when i load the page i echo all the tooltips. How can i repair this?

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem, if you hide the tooltips with css. `jQuery.hide()` adds `display:none;` to the element, so setting this in css for .tooltip-inner should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are selecting **all** the elements with a class of `tooltip-inner`.  You only want your jQuery selectors to apply to the element inside the label you are hovering over.  So wherever you have this selector

```
$('.tooltip-inner')
```

You want to change it to

```
$(this).find('.tooltip-inner')
```